# C++ Include problems in a different file? (Boost include)

Tags: c++, boost

So I am using a library `LibA` that uses Boost inside. I have the following structure:

`Class1.h:`

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H

#include <LibA/major.hpp>
#include <other-useful-libraries.h>

namespace LIB{
class HelperClass{
 ...
};
}
#endif
```

`Class1.cpp`

```
#include <Class1.h>
...Implement Class1...
```

And these two files compile successfully. However, I have another class:

`Class2.h`

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H

#include <Class1.h>
#include <other-useful-libraries.h>

namespace LIB{
class MainClass{
 ...
};
}
#endif
```

`Class2.cpp`

```
#include<Class2.h>
..Implement Class2...
```

However, once I compile this, I get a ton of Boost errors being thrown from Class2.cpp mainly variables not being declared in boost, directive issues, a bunch of `error: expected '}' before end of line`, and many other errors that only point to some problem in the includes. Am I doing something wrong in the includes here?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And also show us the actual errors you get.

Comment: Impossible to know without seeing them. Construct a [MCVE] and post it if that act doesn't reveal the problem. This should be one of your first debugging steps anyway.

Comment: ... but it sounds like you have a typo/bug in `Class2.h` that's killing parsing from then on. Did you forget to close the `namespace LIB{` in your real code?

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up moving #include<Class1.h> to the top and moved #include<LibA/major.hpp> to the top of the includes and it worked. I read that Boost has a bug with dealing with the ordering of the includes as some files have problems with include guards. Hopefully thats a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

I know these errors are very abstract, but just in case anyone comes across this sometime in the future. The error was because of the ordering of the includes. I placed the #include on the very top of the includes, and the file compiled. Boost seems to have a bug with the ordering of includes (with include guards) so make sure its on top.